# How can wrap a post url around featured image in RSS?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this in my functions.php which works fine, I just want the featured image to link to the post.

```
add_filter( 'the_excerpt_rss', 'featured_image_in_feed' );
function featured_image_in_feed( $content ) {
global $post;
if( is_feed() ) {
    if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ){
        $output = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'medium', array( 'style' => 'width:100%; margin-bottom:15px; display: inline-block;' ) );
        $content = $output . $content;
    }
}
return $content;
}
```

This is the output

```
<description><![CDATA[<img width="564" height="153" src="http://mywebsite.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Checklist-crop-ID-85484-564x153.jpg" class="attachment-medium size-medium wp-post-image" alt="checklist" style="width:100%; margin-bottom:15px; display: inline-block;" srcset="http://mywebsite.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Checklist-crop-ID-85484-564x153.jpg 564w, http://mywebsite.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Checklist-crop-ID-85484-768x208.jpg 768w, http://mywebsite.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Checklist-crop-ID-85484.jpg 880w" sizes="(max-width: 564px) 100vw, 564px" />Teaser text is here]]></description>
```

And I'd like it to be

```
<description><![CDATA[<a href="linktothepost"><img width="564" height="153" src="http://mywebsite.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Checklist-crop-ID-85484-564x153.jpg" class="attachment-medium size-medium wp-post-image" alt="checklist" style="width:100%; margin-bottom:15px; display: inline-block;" srcset="http://mywebsite.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Checklist-crop-ID-85484-564x153.jpg 564w, http://mywebsite.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Checklist-crop-ID-85484-768x208.jpg 768w, http://mywebsite.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Checklist-crop-ID-85484.jpg 880w" sizes="(max-width: 564px) 100vw, 564px" /></a>Teaser text is here]]></description>
```

Comment: As opposed to? Show current vs desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `get_post_thumnail()` is just returning a string containing the  tag, you should just be able to wrap the link around that.

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ){
    $output = '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '">';
    $output .= get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'medium', array( 'style' => 'width:100%; margin-bottom:15px; display: inline-block;' ) );
    $output .= '</a>';
    $content = $output . $content;
}
```